# Randomly pick a number between 0 and 8 one by one until there is no number left to pick, then start over

Tags: c++, list, random, enums, numbers

I'm not really a programmer. I'm learning as a I go.
I'm not familiar enough with C++ to know exactly how to do it so I ask here:

I want a logic that will pick a number from 0 to 8 randomly.
Once a number has been picked, it shouldn't be picked again until the program goes through all the numbers from 0 to 8.
Then, once all the number have been eliminated, the program "resets" the list of numbers and restarts the same process endlessly.

I know I'll probably have to do an enum (as I will match other variables to those numbers) but I'm not sure how I'll set up this program.

Comment: what you're looking for is "random shuffle".

Comment: Create an array of numbers from 0 to 8, randomly shuffle the array, then go through them in sequence.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is to randomly shuffle a list of numbers from 0 to 8, print it out in order, then do it all again. For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    while (true) {
        std::vector<int> nums {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        std::random_shuffle(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        for (auto num : nums) {
            std::cout << num << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        // some kind of continuation detection
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...then when you've printed them all, shuffle them again.

Comment: @JerryCoffin that's what the while loop is for

Comment: Right -- I was commenting only on the first sentence of your description.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector with the values : {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Then if a for loop {

Select a random number N between 1 and vector.length() (or size, I don't remember the name)

Pick vector[N-1] and remove the N-1 th element from the vector.

}